# How to change the color of Menu in material-ui v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So far the answers I have found related to change the `Menu` background color are outdated, `@mui/styles` which provides the function makeStyles is now deprecated [mui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api](https://mui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) so I wanted to know how to change the background I tried the following:

```
<Menu
          style={{ background: '#272A31'}} // <- Background Color
            id="menu-appbar"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
```

This is how I have it wrap it:

```
//StyledIconButton Initialization
const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)(
`border-radius: 0;
color:white;

  &:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible {
    background-color: #FF5917
  }`
);

<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
      <StyledIconButton size="small" edge="start" color="inherit" aria-label="menu" sx={{ mr: 2 }} onClick={handleMenu}>
          <GamesIcon />
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}> GAMES </Typography>
          <Menu
          style={{ background: '#272A31'}}
            id="menu-appbar"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
            }}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
          >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} style={{ background: '#272A31', color: "white"}}>GAME A</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} style={{ background: '#272A31', color: "white"}}>GAME B</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} style={{ background: '#272A31', color: "white"}}>GAME C</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} style={{ background: '#272A31', color: "white"}}>GAME D</MenuItem>
          </Menu>
      </StyledIconButton>
      </Box>
```

But by doing that it make the whole screen in that color when I try to open the menu lol:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

**Updated the sandBox for some reason didn't saved correctly last time**
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pike-epxw7?file=/src/App.css)

Comment: have you wraped it around `paper` component?

Comment: I have it wrap it in a Box, let me update it

Comment: add width to the parent component and then simply do the styling part there `paper` component is the thing that they use it in their documentation.

Comment: This is the example I took as reference: [reference](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-responsive-menu)

Comment: They don't use paper in that example they use box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another wrapper in this case paper to wrap my menu and my menu items so that way I can style them.

```
//Initialize the following
   const StyledPaper = styled(Paper)(
  `border-radius: 0;
   color: white;
   background: #272A31;
   `
);

const StyledMenuItem = styled(MenuItem)(
  ` 
    &:hover, &.Mui-focusVisible {
      background-color: #FF5917
    }`
  );

//Then instead of using Paper and MenuItem i'll be using the styled versions I created they have the same functions only thing that changes is their style
    <StyledPaper >
       <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
       <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} id="composition-menu" aria-labelledby="composition-button" onKeyDown={handleListKeyDown}> 
       <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>JUNGLE RAIDER</StyledMenuItem>
            <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>MEGAMAN TEMPLATE</StyledMenuItem>
            <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>TOWER DEFENSE</StyledMenuItem>
            <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>BLADES AND DUNGEON</StyledMenuItem>
            <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleClose}>FIXSPACE</StyledMenuItem>
        </MenuList>
       </ClickAwayListener>
      </StyledPaper>
```

It should look like this (I have to change the zAxis and tweak the origin but got the style/colors I want :3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this properly - that is to say, to not change the whole structure of the MUI component because I wanted to style [this menu](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#account-menu) that is composed of a `<Menu>` component and some `<MenuItem>`.

Here is the solution :

### **The `Menu` component is actually composed of the `List` component.**

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSmz8.png)

So instead of styling the component `MuiMenu` (that will change the background of the whole page), you have to style the component `MuiList`.

On the [Menu API doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu/), they claim there are two ways to style it :

- With a [global class name.](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#global-css) (by importing a CSS file which will contain the following):

```css
    .MuiList-root {
    color: 'white';
    background-color: 'black';
  }
```

- With a rule name as part of the component's `styleOverrides` property in a custom theme (you'll have to import `ThemeProvider, createTheme` and wrap your menu component in the `ThemeProvider` as described on [MUI's doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides) ) :

```js
const theme = createTheme({
      components: {
        MuiList: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              color: 'white',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the styling in the parent component. I tried in my editor and doing that solves the issue.

```
<Box sx={{ background: '#272A31',flexGrow: 0, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
```

and remove the styling from menu element:

```
<Menu style={{no bgColor}} props>
```

Comment: that didn't work on mine sorry, i'll update a sandbox code

Comment: that sounds good. Well did you deleted the styling of `menu` component ?

Comment: yeah I did, didn't work sadly. sandcode up

Comment: try if you can provide a `sandbox`

Comment: just did a sandbox with the answer and it doesn't work for me. I'm using MUI v5 btw

Comment: I fix it but had to change a few things, main thing was to  add another wrapper I used paper and it worked the way I wanted.